Include Application Identifier when scanning barcode using DataWedge in Zebra scanner
I am trying to extract information from barcodes in food industry labels - specifically dates, lot code, UPC, serial #, etc.
We use Zebra devices like TC57, MC9300, MC3300 and when reading barcodes using a specific DataWedge profile, I would like to be able to include the application identifier as well in the scan result. However, that does not come by default.
Attached is an example barcode and I would like to be able to decipher the date and the lot code from this. However, when I scan using the DWDemo app on TC57, I get only the numbers without a special character to separate the variable length lot code. Any help provided will be much appreciated! 
I changed the Keystroke output in the profile setup and changed various options there. That does not seem to work.

Unfortunately, you are dealing with a mal-formed GS1-128 barcode with missing FNC1 codes.  Here is the decode of your image from zxing:

And here is the same text generated as a conforming gs1-128 barcode:

The zxing decode of that barcode is:

Note the two highlighted 0x66 values.  Those are the FNC1 codes required by gs1-128.  The first one says "this is a GS1 symbol" and the second is used to delimit the variable length data.
In order to "read" GS1 data, you need to know which data identifiers are fixed length and which are variable length.  In your text, (01) is a fixed-length 14-digit GTIN, (15) is a fixed YYMMDD date, (10) is a variable-length lot number that must be delimited by FNC1 if less than 20 characters, and finally (240) is variable length product info (which is delimited by end of barcode).

Thank you very much for explaining this! Unfortunately, a lot of the items we receive are like this and we have no control over how our vendors generate their barcodes. Do you know if there is any logic that we can implement to decipher this without the delimiter? For example, can we assume that the information will be in a certain order with lot code/serial number towards the end if present in the barcode?

Without the FNC1 code to delimit variable length data, there is no way to reliably parse the values using a generic handler.  The variable length data could contain what looks like a data-identifier and confuse a general purpose parser.  A possible approach would be to develop a list of regular expressions that match the various barcode formats and apply them one after another until you get a match.  But that is not foolproof...  The variable-length data will always be a potential problem.

Thank you! That is exactly the issue I am running into. I will try to develop a list of regular expressions. Thank you for your suggestion.
